# query never returning results - "Enumeration yielded no results"

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How do I populate a list of `case` objects with two pieces of information from one or more xml files?

Every method I've tried has produced zero results and checking the variable gives ***"Enumeration yielded no results"***. In my code example below, I have included (commented out) various methods I've tried to use to achieve this results.

If there is already an answer out there for this, please point me in that direction. I would appreciate any accompanying explanation as well.

Here are the code snippets:

```
private void gatherInfo(ref List<Case> Cases)
{
    List<string> XMLFileNames = new List<string>();

    foreach (string caseID in txtbxCases.Lines)
    {
        Cases.Add(new Case(caseID));
    }

    XMLFileNames.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(txtbxXMLDirectory.Text, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName));

    string currentFileName = "";

    for (int i = XMLFileNames.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        currentFileName = XMLFileNames[i];
        if (currentFileName.Substring(currentFileName.Length - 4, 4) != ".xml")
        {
            XMLFileNames.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    // Start of Area that doesn't work correctly
    for (int i = XMLFileNames.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        currentFileName = XMLFileNames[i];
        //XElement currentDoc = XElement.Load(txtbxXMLDirectory.Text + "\\" + currentFileName);
        XDocument currentDoc = XDocument.Load(txtbxXMLDirectory.Text + "\\" + currentFileName);
        XElement currentDocElements = XElement.Parse(currentDoc.ToString());

        for (int i2 = Cases.Count - 1; i2>=0; i2--)
        {
            string currentCaseID = Cases[i].GetCaseID();

            IEnumerable<XElement> currentCase =
                from el in currentDocElements.Descendants("Document");
                where (string)el.Element("CaseNumber") == currentCaseID
                select el;
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //var currentCase =
            //    from el in currentDocElements.Descendants("IndexFields")
            //    where (string)el.Element("CaseNumber") == currentCaseID
            //    select el;
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //var currentCase = currentDocElements.Descendants("IndexFields")
            //    .where(x => x.Element("IndexField").Value == currentCaseID);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            foreach (XElement el in currentCase)
            {
                Cases[i].AddFile(el.Element("SRCFilename").Value, el.Element("XMLFilename").Value);
            }
        }
    }

    //foreach (string filename in XMLFileNames)
    //{
    //    XElement currentDoc = XElement.Load(txtbxXMLDirectory.Text + "\\" + filename);
    //
    //    foreach (var caseID in Cases)
    //    {
    //        IEnumerable<XElement> currentCase = 
    //            from el in currentDoc.ElementsAfterSelf("IndexFields")//.Elements("IndexFields")
    //            //where (string)el.Element("CaseNumber") == caseID.GetCaseID()
    //            select el;
    //
    //        foreach (XElement el in currentCase)
    //        {
    //            caseID.AddFile(el.Element("SRCFilename").Value, el.Element("XMLFilename").Value);
    //        }
    //    }
    //}
}
```

Below is an example XML file that includes all of the nesting that the *production* XML files have.

```
 <ImportSession>
 <Batches>
 <Batch BatchClassName="CaseFolder_XML">
 <Documents>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="1"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaa.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aaa.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aaa.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="2"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaa.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aab.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aab.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="3"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaa.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aac.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aac.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="4"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaa.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aad.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aad.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="1"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaa.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aae.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aae.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 <Document FormTypeName="Doc XML Form Type">
 <IndexFields>
 <IndexField Name="CaseNumber" Value="1"/>
 <IndexField Name="XMLFilename" Value="aaf.xml"/>
 <IndexField Name="SRCFilename" Value="aab.pdf"/>
 </IndexFields>
 <Pages>
 <Page ImportFileName="c:\aaf.pdf"/>
 </Pages>
 </Document>
 </Documents>
 </Batch>
 </Batches>
 </ImportSession>
```

The following are true in production:

- Multiple xml files to check
- A case may show up multiple times in an xml file
- The same files can be added to multiple cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("a.xml");
var allDocs = xDoc.Descendants("Document")
                .Select(doc=>new{
                    FormTypeName = doc.Attribute("FormTypeName").Value,
                    IndexFields = doc.Descendants("IndexField")
                                    .ToDictionary(x=>x.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                                  x=>x.Attribute("Value").Value)
                })
                .ToList();
```

You can also use XPath

```
string xpath = "//Document[IndexFields/IndexField[@Name='CaseNumber' and @Value='3']]";
var docElement = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should be reading `Cases[i2]` instead of `Cases[i]`?

```
for (int i2 = Cases.Count - 1; i2>=0; i2--)
{     // ^ counter for iterating over "Cases"

    string currentCaseID = Cases[i2].GetCaseID();
                              // ^ use correct counter here

    IEnumerable<XElement> currentCase =
        from el in currentDocElements.Descendants("Document");
        where (string)el.Element("CaseNumber") == currentCaseID
        select el;

    foreach (XElement el in currentCase)
    {
        Cases[i2].AddFile(el.Element("SRCFilename").Value, el.Element("XMLFilename").Value);
           // ^ and here
    }
```

Comment: D'oh...  Definitely a bug...  Tried that, still no go - I still don't get any results...  "Enumeration yielded no results" is the bane of me!